# Reducing dimensionality of features with PCA in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pca

I'm totally confused regarding PCA. I have a 4D image of size 90x60x12x350. That means that each voxel is a vector of size 350 (time series).

Now I divide the 3D image (90x60x12) into cubes. So let's say a cube contains n voxels, so I have n vectors of size 350. I want to reduce this `n` vectors to only one vector and then calculate the correlations between all vectors of all cubes.

So for a cube I can construct the matrix `M` where I just put each voxel after each other, i.e. `M = [v1 v2 v3 ... vn]` and each `v` is of size 350.

Now I can apply PCA in Matlab by using `[coeff, score, latent, ~, explained] = pca(M);` and taking the first component. And now my confusion begins.

1. Should I transpose the matrix `M`, i.e. `PCA(M')`?
2. Should I take the first column of coeff or of score?
3. This third question is now a bit unrelated. Let's assume we have a
   matrix `A = rand(30,100)` where the rows are the datapoints and the
   columns are the features. Now I want to reduce the dimensionality of
   the feature vectors but keeping all data points.

   How can I do this with PCA?

   When I do `[coeff, score, latent, ~, explained] = pca(M);` then
   coeff is of dimension 100x29 and score is of size 30x29. I'm
   totally confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, according to the `pca` help, "Rows of X correspond to observations and columns to variables."
2. `score` just tells you the representation of `M` in the principal component space. You want the first column of `coeff`.
3. ```
   numberOfDimensions = 5;
   coeff = pca(A);
   reducedDimension = coeff(:,1:numberOfDimensions);
   reducedData = A * reducedDimension;
   ```

Comment: @ribond Should I apply z score (zero mean, unit variance) before applying PCA (z score on the columns of M) or should I apply it before feeding the feature vectors to my machine learning classifier (z score on each feature vector)?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the answer above.

```
[coeff,score]=pca(A)
```

where A has rows as observations and column as features.

If A has 3 featuers and >3 observations (Let's say 100) and you want the "feature" of 2 dimensions, say matrix B (the size of B is 100X2). What you should do is:

```
B = score(:,1:2);
```